# Increasing USB 5V current the right way

Tags: usb, current, 5v

USB2 is limited to 500mA. If you want more current you need an external PSU to pump in more juice. What would be the proper way to add another 5V PSU to the system?

1. Connect the 5V from the PSU to the 5V of the USB?
2. Ignore the USB 5V and use only the PSU 5V?

In most cases (Well, 100%) the voltages are not the same and this might cause unwanted currents. GND of the USB and PSU must be connected though.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the edit you made. Your original version was correct. The voltages are never exactly the same. Now it reads as a double negative, which means they are always the same (which is not correct).

Comment: Also, are you referring to the PSU as specifically the power supply of your computer? Or do you mean any generic external power supply?

Comment: @DanLaks - I was confused too, so I've edited it but not enough reputation to publish.

Comment: I refer to an external psu, nothing to do with the computer

Comment: Are you trying to power something that takes 5V, and more current than a USB 2 power source 0.5A provide (and the USB socket doesn't matter)? Or are you trying to power something via the USB 2 socket?

Comment: trying to power somthing that needs more than 0.5A which is what usb2 supplies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have the right idea about how this should work. If you hook up two separate power supplies set to the same voltage, there will always be a small difference that will cause current to flow from one source to the other. Inevitably, the "stronger" supply will tend to drive the weaker supply higher or lower to match it. Usually not a good thing. Connecting two power sources in parallel is not impossible, however. For example, you can connect two parallel battery packs to your circuit by just using diodes in series with each one. The pack with higher voltage will initially take most of the load, but as it drops in voltage from use, the other pack will start to take over. Eventually the load will draw from both packs equally.

If your load will draw a large current (much greater than 500mA), #2 on your list is probably the best idea. And yes, you would want to tie the ground of the USB port to the ground of your power supply.

Incidentally, you've got a hefty 5V power supply right there in your computer (assuming you have a tower PC... not applicable to a laptop). The red wires on any unused peripheral power plug are 5V, yellow is +12V, and black is ground. The other colors are negative voltages, which I assume aren't useful to you right now.
[image]

If your load will only draw a little more than 500mA, but a bit less than 1A, you could also just use two USB ports together in parallel. This is common in external USB disc drivers. They come with two USB plugs on them. One has power and data, the other just power.
[image]